# R - Pmap() instead of Map()

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr

Follow bellow the database in `nest()` format.

```
x <- list( factory = c('a','b','c','d'), cost = c(21,30,44,100))
    x <- as.data.frame(x)
    x <-  x %>%
            melt('cost','factory')
    colnames(x) <- c('cost','client','type')
    x <- x %>%
      group_by(client)%>%
      nest()

    for (m in 1:4) {
      if(m==1){
        x$scene <- m
        x2 <- x
      }else{
        x3 <- x
        x3$scene <- m
        x2 <- rbind(x2,x3)
      }
    }
    x2 <- x2 %>%
      group_by(scene) %>%
      nest()
```

It's already working with `map()` function but instead of keep using `map()`, I would like to change to `pmap()` without lose the `nest()` format. Follow the code that I am using.

```
test <- function(df){
    mutate(df, increa = cost + 15)
}

map(x2$data, ~ map(.x$data, test)) 

x2_new <- x2 %>%    mutate(data = map(data, function(df1) mutate(df1,
data = map(data, test))))
```

The result:

```
dput(x2_new)
```

> structure(list(scene = 1:4, data = list(structure(list(client =
>   structure(1L, .Label = "factory", class = "factor"), 
>       data = list(structure(list(cost = c(21, 30, 44, 100), type = c("a", 
>       "b", "c", "d"), increa = c(36, 45, 59, 115)), row.names = c(NA, 
>       -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))), row.names = c(NA, 
>   -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(
>       client = structure(1L, .Label = "factory", class = "factor"), 
>       data = list(structure(list(cost = c(21, 30, 44, 100), type = c("a", 
>       "b", "c", "d"), increa = c(36, 45, 59, 115)), row.names = c(NA, 
>       -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))), row.names = c(NA, 
>   -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(
>       client = structure(1L, .Label = "factory", class = "factor"), 
>       data = list(structure(list(cost = c(21, 30, 44, 100), type = c("a", 
>       "b", "c", "d"), increa = c(36, 45, 59, 115)), row.names = c(NA, 
>       -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))), row.names = c(NA, 
>   -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(
>       client = structure(1L, .Label = "factory", class = "factor"), 
>       data = list(structure(list(cost = c(21, 30, 44, 100), type = c("a", 
>       "b", "c", "d"), increa = c(36, 45, 59, 115)), row.names = c(NA, 
>       -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))), row.names = c(NA, 
>   -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))), row.names = c(NA, 
>   -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

The code works following this script with `pmap()`, but I cant keep it the `nest()` format

```
pmap(list(x2$data), ~ pmap(list(.x$data), test))
```

Comment: You could simplify this question greatly and make it easier to help with if you just give a sample of the data ready to deal with the issue. In this case, as far as I can understand looking at your code, we only need what's in the second code block, so just `dput` the data as it is when `map` needs to be called.

Comment: Done, sorry @camille

Comment: I think I wasn't super clear. If what we need to work with to help debug is your final version of `x2` (is that correct?), just post `dput(x2)` as the data for us to work with, not all the stuff in the first code block where you generate that data.

Comment: R is case sensitive, `Map` and `map` are different functions, `Pmap` doesn't exist in `base` / `purrr`